# Git rebase leaves current branch behind remote, want a cleaner commit history

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I upload commits from my local Git repo to GitHub regularly, but it was overloaded with commits, and after deciding they are not useful and just spoil the history, I tried using `rebase -i` to squash some of the commits together.

It seemed to work, so I wanted to push the changed commits to GitHub and change the history there. What I get is that the tip of my current branch is behind. And the suggested action is to pull changes from the remote repo, but I don't want the changes from the remote. I just want to send what I have locally to GitHub.

Can you please explain me the situation a bit and help to achieve what I want?

Comment: what says the commit-messages of these commits? Who is the author of this commits? I use github and have not ever seen such commits on my repos.

Comment: I added the commits myself, but now I think that I don't need them and I want to remove them from the history. - For example I added new things to a file 5 times and pushed it to github 5 times, so I have 5 commits saying `Add new information`. Now I want to squash them into just one and this change to be reflected in the Github repo, too, not just in my local one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit some pushed branches is a no-go, however you can do it.

maybe your commit log looks like this:

```
o 250a32c added new information <master> <origin/master>
|
o c4f5265 added new information
|
o 168d674 added new information
|
o ca708cd some other commit
```

You can now with interactive rebase squash some commits.

```
git rebase -i ca708cd
```

An editor opens and you can change the `pick` before the commits `250a32c` and `c4f5265` to `squash`.

After this, your repo looks like this:

```
o 3e86bc4 added new information <master>
| o 250a32c added new information <origin/master>
| |
| o c4f5265 added new information
| |
| o 168d674 added new information
|/
o ca708cd some other commit
```

Now you have to need to push your branch to the github with `--force`, because your master and master/origin are out of sync and cannot be fast-forwarded.

```
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) `--force` was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting history after you have published commit publicly is not a very good thing to do. Imagine someone else cloned your repository. If you change it afterwards, their history wouldn't match their origin (your github repo).

You have several solutions, you can:

- try and go on and change the repo on github. One possibility is to completely discard the branches you don't like on github, and then push your arranged local branches to github (silvio's "--force" being a faster alternative).
- remove the repo completely and clone your local repo to github again.
- live with the not so beautiful commits (preferred solution).

Comment: Thank you! :) I know that I shouldn't rewrite history, but this is a repository just for me, where I keep some notes about interesting things I have read while learning, it's not even programming code and I doubt that someone knows about my repository, so I think it's safe. I just didn't like to have several commits which are almost the same :)